# NSCalendar - ordinal number of week changes at 23:58:45

Tags: ios, objective-c, nscalendar

I'm trying to get the ordinal number of a week using NSCalendar so that I can calculate the number of weeks between two dates, however the method I'm using is demonstrating some weird behaviour.

I'm expecting a new week to begin every Sunday at 00:00:00, but instead it seems to happen at 23:58:45. I've tried changing the `firstWeekday` property of the calendar but that doesn't have any effect.

**Example Code** (note: 2014-03-09 is a Sunday)

```
- (void)testTimeWeeksBegins
{
    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

    // Make NSDates
    NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    comps.year = 2014;
    comps.month = 3;
    comps.day = 9;
    comps.hour = 23;
    comps.minute = 58;
    comps.second = 44;

    NSDateComponents *compsToAdd = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    compsToAdd.second = 1;

    NSDate *date23_58_44 = [calendar dateFromComponents:comps];
    NSDate *date23_58_45 = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:compsToAdd toDate:date23_58_44 options:0];

    // Calculate ordinality of week on both dates
    NSUInteger ord23_58_44 = [calendar ordinalityOfUnit:NSWeekOfYearCalendarUnit inUnit:NSEraCalendarUnit forDate:date23_58_44];
    NSUInteger ord23_58_45 = [calendar ordinalityOfUnit:NSWeekOfYearCalendarUnit inUnit:NSEraCalendarUnit forDate:date23_58_45];

    // Output
    NSLog(@"Date is %@ and week number is %d", date23_58_44, ord23_58_44);
    NSLog(@"Date is %@ and week number is %d", date23_58_45, ord23_58_45);


}
```

**Output**

```
Date is 2014-03-09 23:58:44 +0000 and week number is 105043
Date is 2014-03-09 23:58:45 +0000 and week number is 105044
```

Am I being stupid and missing something obvious or is this a bug? I suppose my workaround would be to use a date with a time after 23:58:45, to ensure no problems in future?

Comment: I get 105044 in both instances when running your code. What time zone are you in?

Comment: GMT. Which are you in?

Comment: German time (GMT+1), but I set the calendar's timezone to GMT to check your results. I got exactly your dates, but 105044 for both week ordinals (as one would expect).

Comment: That's really strange. I tried both simulator and my iPhone and got the output I got before. I'm struggling to think what else it could be.